# How do i add a value based on id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a drop down box that if the payload has no id it should show "please select" by adding in the value "selected: true" to the object in the item array, but if the payload has a user id it should be put in to that users object.

code before payload

```
const users = {

  label: {
    text: 'Select User'
  },
  items: [
    {
      value: 'Please Select',
      text: 'Please Select',
      selected: true
    },
    {
      value: '2',
      text: 'Tom'
    },
    {
      value: '3',
      text: 'Dick'
    },
    {
      value: '4',
      text: 'Harry'
    }
  ]
}
```

how i want the code to look code after payload based on the incoming value, value 2 in items now has selected: true

```
payload = { value : 2 }

const users = {

  label: {
    text: 'Select User'
  },
  items: [
    {
      value: 'Please Select',
      text: 'Please Select'
    },
    {
      value: '2',
      text: 'Tom',
      selected: true
    },
    {
      value: '3',
      text: 'Dick'
    },
    {
      value: '4',
      text: 'Harry'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is your problem ? its unclear. What have you tried ?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: first block of code is how it looks, second block is how i want to to look after the payload based on the value in the payload

Comment: Well, we can see what you want,  so now what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Click edit, click the `[<>]` snippet editor and add relevant JS and HTML to show what your mean

Answer (score 1):

```js
const users = {

  label: {
    text: 'Select User'
  },
  items: [
    {
      value: 'Please Select',
      text: 'Please Select',
      selected: true
    },
    {
      value: '2',
      text: 'Tom'
    },
    {
      value: '3',
      text: 'Dick'
    },
    {
      value: '4',
      text: 'Harry'
    }
  ]
}; 

payload = { value : 2 };

let items = users.items.map(( o ) =>  {
 if(o.selected) {
  delete o.selected
 }
 if(Number(o.value) === Number(payload.value)) {
  o.selected = true;
 }
 return o;
});

let result =  {
  label: {
    text: 'Select User'
  },
  items: items
};

console.log(result);
```

You can iterate on items and add new property on basics of payload and delete other selected property

Answer (score 0):

You can add property `selected` for every object with default value `false`, then try to make a function like this

```
function changeProrertyValue(valueNumber){
 for(let item of user.items){
  if(item.value===valueNumber){
   if(item.selected){
    item.selected = false;
   }else{
    item.selected = true;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the value in your payload was not a string so we have to cast to number to compare

```js
var payload1 = { value : 2 } 
var payload2 = { text : 'Dick' }

let users = { label: { text: 'Select User' }, 
              items: [ { value: 'Please Select', text: 'Please Select' }, { value: '2', text: 'Tom', }, { value: '3', text: 'Dick' }, { value: '4', text: 'Harry' } ] }

const changeUser = (users, payload) => {
  users.items.forEach(item => {
    if (payload.value !== null && +item.value === +payload.value) {
      item["selected"] = true;
    } else if (payload.text !== null && item.text === payload.text) {
      item["selected"] = true;
    } else delete item["selected"];
  })
  return users
};
users = changeUser(users, payload1)
console.log(users)
users = changeUser(users, payload2)
console.log(users)
```